# Chart.JS Time Axis Not Parsing

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Kia ora! I am trying to implement a Chart.JS time cartesian axis. I've read the docs and found out I need to add a datetime library and adapter as of `v3.x.x`, so I've done that.

For some reason all my data points are on time=0 from what I can tell. It's like the time value is not being parsed properly, I think.

> Chart.js uses timestamps defined as milliseconds since the epoch (midnight January 1, 1970, UTC) internally. However, Chart.js also supports all of the formats that your chosen date adapter accepts. You should use timestamps if you'd like to set parsing: false for better performance.

So, I have configured my API to return millisecond timestamps and defined `parsing:false` in the x axis options.

Here is a broken Codepen: https://codepen.io/Finnito/pen/KKqgXez, but the code is also attached below.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var weeklyHistoryChartEl = document.getElementById('weeklyHistory').getContext('2d');
  var weeklyHistoryChart = new Chart(weeklyHistoryChartEl, { 
      type: 'line',
      scales: {
        x: {
          type: 'time',
          parsing: false
        }
      }
  });
  weeklyHistoryChart.data = JSON.parse('{"datasets":[{"data":[{"x":1625443200,"y":11.74},{"x":1626048000,"y":12.43},{"x":1626652800,"y":34.18}],"label":"Hike","hidden":true},{"data":[{"x":1624233600,"y":5.27},{"x":1630281600,"y":7.32}],"label":"Kayaking","hidden":true},{"data":[{"x":1626652800,"y":17.99}],"label":"NordicSki","hidden":true},{"data":[{"x":1623024000,"y":9.98},{"x":1623628800,"y":15.97},{"x":1624233600,"y":29.07},{"x":1624838400,"y":57.26},{"x":1625443200,"y":15.87},{"x":1627257600,"y":40.73},{"x":1627862400,"y":29.87},{"x":1628467200,"y":58.87},{"x":1629072000,"y":7.62},{"x":1629676800,"y":21.52},{"x":1630281600,"y":6.03}],"label":"Ride","hidden":true},{"data":[{"x":1628467200,"y":0}],"label":"RockClimbing","hidden":true},{"data":[{"x":1623628800,"y":92.45},{"x":1624233600,"y":31.24},{"x":1624838400,"y":23.81},{"x":1625443200,"y":9.39},{"x":1626048000,"y":40.94},{"x":1626652800,"y":12.84},{"x":1627257600,"y":33.59},{"x":1627862400,"y":30.97},{"x":1628467200,"y":31.88},{"x":1629072000,"y":27.88},{"x":1629676800,"y":47.23},{"x":1630281600,"y":48.1}],"label":"Run","hidden":false},{"data":[{"x":1627862400,"y":30.2},{"x":1628467200,"y":36.24},{"x":1629676800,"y":85.58},{"x":1630281600,"y":52.81}],"label":"VirtualRide","hidden":true},{"data":[{"x":1623024000,"y":6.78},{"x":1626048000,"y":5.92}],"label":"Walk","hidden":true},{"data":[{"x":1623628800,"y":0},{"x":1628467200,"y":0}],"label":"Yoga","hidden":true}]}');
  weeklyHistoryChart.update();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.2.1/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-date-fns/dist/chartjs-adapter-date-fns.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/date-fns/1.30.1/date_fns.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="weeklyHistory"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scales are part of the options object, if you place it in the options it works just fine:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var weeklyHistoryChartEl = document.getElementById('weeklyHistory').getContext('2d');
  var weeklyHistoryChart = new Chart(weeklyHistoryChartEl, {
    type: 'line',
    options: {
      scales: {
        x: {
          type: 'time',
          parsing: false
        }
      }
    }
  });
  weeklyHistoryChart.data = JSON.parse('{"datasets":[{"data":[{"x":1625443200,"y":11.74},{"x":1626048000,"y":12.43},{"x":1626652800,"y":34.18}],"label":"Hike","hidden":true},{"data":[{"x":1624233600,"y":5.27},{"x":1630281600,"y":7.32}],"label":"Kayaking","hidden":true},{"data":[{"x":1626652800,"y":17.99}],"label":"NordicSki","hidden":true},{"data":[{"x":1623024000,"y":9.98},{"x":1623628800,"y":15.97},{"x":1624233600,"y":29.07},{"x":1624838400,"y":57.26},{"x":1625443200,"y":15.87},{"x":1627257600,"y":40.73},{"x":1627862400,"y":29.87},{"x":1628467200,"y":58.87},{"x":1629072000,"y":7.62},{"x":1629676800,"y":21.52},{"x":1630281600,"y":6.03}],"label":"Ride","hidden":true},{"data":[{"x":1628467200,"y":0}],"label":"RockClimbing","hidden":true},{"data":[{"x":1623628800,"y":92.45},{"x":1624233600,"y":31.24},{"x":1624838400,"y":23.81},{"x":1625443200,"y":9.39},{"x":1626048000,"y":40.94},{"x":1626652800,"y":12.84},{"x":1627257600,"y":33.59},{"x":1627862400,"y":30.97},{"x":1628467200,"y":31.88},{"x":1629072000,"y":27.88},{"x":1629676800,"y":47.23},{"x":1630281600,"y":48.1}],"label":"Run","hidden":false},{"data":[{"x":1627862400,"y":30.2},{"x":1628467200,"y":36.24},{"x":1629676800,"y":85.58},{"x":1630281600,"y":52.81}],"label":"VirtualRide","hidden":true},{"data":[{"x":1623024000,"y":6.78},{"x":1626048000,"y":5.92}],"label":"Walk","hidden":true},{"data":[{"x":1623628800,"y":0},{"x":1628467200,"y":0}],"label":"Yoga","hidden":true}]}');
  weeklyHistoryChart.update();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.2.1/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-date-fns/dist/chartjs-adapter-date-fns.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/date-fns/1.30.1/date_fns.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="weeklyHistory"></canvas>
```

https://codepen.io/leelenaleee/pen/MWojOwv

Comment: Damn, that makes a lot of sense. Just quickly, the timestamps in the data are for different weeks, not the same day at different times. What do you think is going on there?

Comment: They are not, try calling `new Date(timeStamp)` and replace timestamp with a random timestamp from one of your datapoints and you will see its all the same day

Comment: Hmmm, if I use https://www.epochconverter.com/. 1625443200 is Monday, July 5, 2021 12:00:00 AM, and 1626048000 is Monday, July 12, 2021 12:00:00 AM for example.

Comment: And in the console:

new Date(1625443200000)
Date Mon Jul 05 2021 12:00:00 GMT+1200 (New Zealand Standard Time)

new Date(1626048000000)
Date Mon Jul 12 2021 12:00:00 GMT+1200 (New Zealand Standard Time)

Comment: Ah whoops, there's the second vs millisecond problem.

Comment: All good now with a working example over here! https://codepen.io/Finnito/pen/KKqgXez. Many thanks!